# ASP.NET MVC debugging following VS2010 uninstall

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging

OK this is an odd one.

I wanted to install ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta 2, so I uninstalled VS2010 Beta 2 (which I wasn't using anyway) and installed MVC 2.

I then upgraded one of my projects to MVC 2 but noticed that if I try to set a breakpoint on any of my view models (classes in the Models folder) I get an error message about debug symbols.

***"The breakpoint will not currently be hit..."***

Then I tried to debug one of my old MVC 1 projects and noticed the same symptom.

I've now uninstalled MVC beta 2, repaired Visual Studio 2008 and still get this with my existing projects.

What's especially strange is that breakpoints anywhere else in the project (controllers, helper methods etc) ARE being hit successfully.

So I guess the question is, what is unique about my view models in the models folder that is causing breakpoints to not be loaded.

Here is an example view model...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MountKitSearch.Core.DTO.MountKit;

namespace MountKitSearch.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class MountKitSearchViewModel
    {
        public string Distributor { get; set; }
        public SelectList VehicleMakes;
        public SelectList VehicleModels;
        public SelectList VehicleTypes;
        public SelectList VehicleEngines;
        public ICollection<MountKitDetailsDTO> MountKits;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure which of the two events (uninstalling VS2010, installing MVC2) caused the problem!

Comment: Now I'm completely stuck. I've uninstalled MVC1 and MVC2, uninstalled VS2008 and every related installation I can think of.

Then I've reinstalled VS2008 and MVC1, create a brand new MVC1 project and still getting "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" when attempting to break into a view model in the Models folder.

Comment: Is your website running in IIS or CASINI? Have you deleted your temporary asp.net files folder? Have you rerun aspnet_regiis ? Have you created a new website/virtual folder?

Comment: Casini, I've deleted temporary asp.net files and rerun aspnet_regiis

Comment: I've now checked the modules when debugging and the only one showing errors about pdb files is CppCodeProvider.dll

Comment: hmm I think I was being a bit stupid! I was trying to set a breakpoint on an automatic property.

This is something I could have sworn I'd done before, but actually (now I think about it) it doesn't make a huge amount of sense (there's no logic in there to debug anyway).

If I add a method to this same view model, the breakpoint works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to debug an Automatic Property was actually the cause of this error.

There is no good reason to debug an automatic property (as by definition they contain no logic).

All other breakpoints are working fine (and I am an idiot!).